# Facebook iOS app authorization produces blank screen

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on

I am successfully authorization Facebook access using the graph and would like to provide Single sign on if the user has the Facebook app installed.
When I attempt this, I get the Facebook app to launch, but get a blank screen with a cancel button.
Here is the URL I use:

fbauth://authorize?type=user_agent&display=touch&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&sdk=ios&scope=read_friendlists%2Cfriends_website%2Cuser_website%2Cuser_relationships%2Cpublish_stream%2Cfriends_birthday%2Cfriends_interests%2Cfriends_work_history%2Cfriends_groups%2Cuser_photos%2Cfriends_photos%2Cphoto_upload%2Cread_stream%2Cstatus_update&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxx

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the Facebook SDK for iOS to authenticate the user?

Comment: Yet another unresolved Facebook blank page question.

Comment: Have you found a solution @Rick Schlueter?